# Issue when editing a user, how to store the properly encoded password?

Tags: symfony

I'm not using FOSUserBundle, I created the entity user, roles and etc on my own. The configuration goes as follows:

```
security:
    encoders:
          Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
            algorithm: sha512
            encode-as-base64: true
            iterations: 10
```

and when creating I do this:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
            $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($entity);
            $entity->setSalt(md5(time()));
            $entity->setCompany($company);
            $encoded_password = $encoder->encodePassword($entity->getPassword(), $entity->getSalt());
            $entity->setPassword($encoded_password);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user'));
        }
```

however when editing any user the password shows as:

```
2cp/D6OTBEx4m2Y9xM/ku6rOtgODhrXK7//3Pd8D0jnZkOuusPB120Jwb6x+kan/52qSQuQxcUYDP1T6q6zqbw==
```

but if I save any other changes the password gets overwritten and I can no longer access, same if I input a new password, it doesn't get encoded (obviously because I'm not doing anything on the updateAction) but I'd like to know what is the right approach in order to accomplish this?

Using preUpdate? Separating the password field in "edit" so the field doesn't get overwritten?

Comment: I would use another property for the password (FOSUserBundle uses `plainPassword`) and then, in a prePersist/preUpdate listener, if plainPassword is not null do the encoding and update the actual password field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [repeated Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html) for set password. If you miss them in user edit form, the doctrine do not update them in DB and it not overridden.

- And also do not use `notBlank` validator for password!

  ```
  $oldPass = $entity->getPassword();
  // Handle form from request
  if ($form->isValid()) {
      if ($entity->getPassword() == '' || $entity->getPassword() == NULL) {
          $entity->setPassword($oldPass);
      } else {
          $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
          $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($entity);
          $entity->setSalt(md5(time()));
          $entity->setCompany($company);
          $encoded_password = $encoder->encodePassword($entity->getPassword(), $entity->getSalt());
          $entity->setPassword($encoded_password);
      }
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $em->persist($entity);
      $em->flush();

      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user'));
  }
  ```

Comment: Hello, although it does not show the password when editing, if I edit any other field a blank password is stored.

Comment: Also use preUpdate for password encoding. And what version of Symfony do you use?

Comment: I was just doing something similar to this however I couldn't get the old password, then realize I was getting the password after handling the request, resulting in the already empty password. I'm using 2.3.x version